# Matching string with shell-style wildcards (e.g., *)

Tags: php, string, wildcard

Is it possible to use a wildcard in an if statement?

My code:

`*` = wildcard

```
if ($admin =='*@some.text.here') {

}
```

`$admin` will be one of these:

- xvilo@some.text.here
- bot!bot@some.text.here
- lakjsdflkjasdflkj@some.text.here

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: No, but you can probably use preg_match to so what you want.

Comment: what does this have to do with IRC?

Comment: The `if` does not enter into it. The `==` is what prevents you from using wildcards. Look for an alternative to `==`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you don't want to use regular expressions, [`fnmatch()`](http://php.net/fnmatch) might serve you well for this [limited] purpose. It matches strings using shell-like wildcards like you are expecting.

```
if (fnmatch('*@some.text.here', $admin)) {

}
```

Comment: I'm gonna give you a +1 for that I've never even noticed that function before very useful.

Comment: fnmatch fails with warnings about filenames being longer than 4096 characters. Since I'm matching a dataset not filename I can't use fnmatch

Answer (score 3):

You could just check that the string ends with the value you are expecting:

```
$suffix = '@some.text.here';

if (substr($admin, -strlen($suffix)) == $suffix) {
    // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a wildcard function for you.
As you are looking to use `*` only I've commented out the `.` (single character match).

This will allow you to use wildcards throughout:
`*xxx` - ends "xxx"
`xxx*` - starts "xxx"
`xx*zz` - begins with "xx" and ends with "zz"
`*xx*` - has "xx" in the middle

```
function wildcard_match($pattern, $subject)
{
    $pattern='/^'.preg_quote($pattern).'$/';
    $pattern=str_replace('\*', '.*', $pattern);
    //$pattern=str_replace('\.', '.', $pattern);
    if(!preg_match($pattern, $subject, $regs)) return false;
    return true;
}
if (wildcard_match('*@some.text.here', $admin)) {

}
```

BUT I suggest learning to use [regular expressions](http://regular-expressions.info) with `preg_match()` yourself.

Comment: ooooh! never seen that before! Nice!

Answer (score 1):

```
if (strstr ($admin,"@some.text.here")) {

}
```

use strstr() it'll do what you want or as pointed out stristr()

Or you can use strpos something like this

```
$pos = strrpos($mystring, "@some.text.here");
if ($pos === false) { // note: three equal signs
    // not found...
} else {
    //found
}
```

Or from end (I think not tested it)

```
$checkstring = "@some.text.here";
$pos = strrpos($mystring, $checkstring, -(strlen($checkstring)));
if ($pos === false) { // note: three equal signs
    // not found...
} else {
    //found
}
```

Comment: stristr is the case insensitive version of this

Comment: This does assume that it doesn't matter if `@some.text.here` is at the end of the string or not.

Comment: He didn't state in his example if he was being specific about it being in a certain location in the text just that it was in the text.  You can always use strpos with a strlen - offset though if you want to search from the end of the string rather than anywhere

Comment: foo@some.text.here looks like an email address to me in which case @some.text.here is likely meant to be at the end of the string.  Since there are many assumptions we can make on what the OP *intended* it's better to cover all bases for completeness :)

Comment: I disagree. The intent seemed fairly clear. The example was not `$admin =='*@some.text.here*'` with a `*` on the end.

Comment: @Emissary wiseguy true I guess I can post some search from end changes up in a second. uɐɥʇɐᴎ because both are potential options there was no mention made of speed and tbh I'm not entirely sure myself of the performance differentials between the 2 methods

Comment: I wouldn't worry about micro-optimizations here. Do what works correctly and is most easily understood. Don't sacrifice that for the sake of saving 0.000052 seconds. If you're looping over billions of items, then it might be worthwhile. Maybe. (If correctness and clarity are the same, then yeah, encourage the "best practice" and use the more efficient one. But if you must sacrifice correctness or clarity, it's not worth it IMO.)

Comment: @Wiseguy I pretty much agree. Nathan it really mentions speed difference in the php docs? I don't think so or you're looking at different docs to me http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php no mention of speed at all there.  There's also little/no point in micro optimising on a small scale site its not bad practice its just being pragmatic

Comment: @Dave In [`strstr()` docs](http://php.net/strstr): _"Note:
If you only want to determine if a particular needle occurs within haystack, use the faster and less memory intensive function strpos() instead."_

Comment: @wiseguy got me there I didn't look at the docs at all I tend to work from memory and only look up when I'm not sure on syntax.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest method to check if a string is found in another string would be strpos():

```
if (strpos($admin, '@some.test.here') !== false) { }
```

If you need to be certain that @some.text.here occurs at the end, you'll want to use substr_compare() instead.

```
if (substr_compare($str, $test, strlen($str)-strlen($test), strlen($test)) === 0) {}
```

Comment: if it starts with that, the returned position is 0 = false - see Dave's answer

Comment: If the problem is that `0` is implicitly converted to `false`, _explicitly_ converting it to `false` (with `!!` or direct casting) isn't going to change that.

Comment: Oh wow, absolutely correct. Don't know what I was thinking on that.